# Get user used values out of FormGroup angular 6

Tags: angular6, form-control

I am building a search panel and used reactive forms. I am having 12 fields in that form (ex: fistName, lastname, address......). None of the fields are assigned "required" in the formgroup. User can enter any amount of fields to search. Is there any way i could use to find how many fields user have entered. Say a user used only 5 fields out of 12 to search, i want to return 5. I had used single search like for each fields;

```
if (this.searchPanelForm.get('event').value) {
  //increase the count
}
```

and it is working fine. But i dont think it is an efficient way to solve the problem and have to change the code each time another field is added or removed. Can someone suggest any solution.

And this is how my form group is:

```
public searchPanelForm: FormGroup;
constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
) { }
ngOnInit() {
 this.searchPanelForm = this._fb.group({
  name: [''],
  name1: [''],
  name2: [''],
  name3: [''],
  name4: [''],
  name5: [''],
  name6: [''],
  name7: [''],
  name8: ['']
});
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, you **clone** the form value and stores it in a variable, let's say, `oldFormValue`, then when you need to find out how many fields were entered subsequently, you can compare the previous form value and the new one, like below

```
getNumberOfFieldsChanged(newFormValue, oldFormValue) {
  return Object.keys(oldFormValue)
               .reduce((sum, nextKey) -> {
                 if (oldFormValue[nextKey] !== newFormValue[nextKey])
                   sum++;
                 return sum;
               }, 0);
}
```

You **must** clone the form value and assign it to `oldFormValue` variable, or else, the new value and the old one will refer to the same object which will cause the method above to always return 0